# Group time intervals by date (in d3.js)

Tags: d3.js

For instance, there is an array of objects with `start`, `end` and `duration` (in hours) attributes.

```
[{start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 0),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 4, 8),
  duration: 8},
 {start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 22),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 5, 2),
  duration: 4},
 {start: new Date(2013, 2, 5, 5),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 7, 5),
  duration: 48}]
```

I'd like to visualize them into something like the following (`y` - hours, `x` - dates):

[image]

I'm thinking about creating additional objects to fill the empty spaces between events like this

```
[{start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 0),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 4, 8),
  status: "busy"},

 {start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 8, 0, 1),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 4, 21, 59, 59),
  status: "free"},

 {start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 22),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 4, 23, 59, 59),
  status: "busy"},

 {start: new Date(2013, 2, 5, 0),
  end:   new Date(2013, 2, 5, 2),
  status: "busy"}]
```

And then map this to [Stack Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#).

So my question is, how would be better to split and group the array, to make this visualization easier? Maybe there is some built-in D3.js features for this?

Comment: Sounds like the format you propose would be quite suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider changing the data format to

```
    [{start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 0),
      end:   new Date(2013, 2, 4, 8)},
     {start: new Date(2013, 2, 4, 22),
      end:   new Date(2013, 2, 5, 2)},
     {start: new Date(2013, 2, 5, 5),
      end:   new Date(2013, 2, 7, 5)}]
```

Since you have the start and end date, you don't really need a duration. Alternatively you could have just the start date and a duration.

I'm not extremely familiar with the stacklayout, but it might be sufficent (and easier) for this project to simply append `rect` elements to the right position. I made an example here: http://tributary.io/inlet/5841372 which doesn't take into account the fact that you need to wrap events that start one day and end the next. This just displays all events in the same column, with the white space representing free time.

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions about the example code, or about getting your code to do what you want, I'll be on pretty often and happy to help.

Comment: Oops, and I see I had a mistake. The `"y"` attribute of the `rect`'s should be set to `function(d) {return d.start;}` rather than `d.end`. I've updated the example code.